# Cartesian product and Join in logical query tree

Tags: mysql, sql, database

im currently working on logical query tree, can someone explain me what is difference between cartesian product and join in logical tree.

I know that `JOIN` combines the two or more records but displays only matching values, but i dont understand when i should use `Join` and when `Cartesian product`.

Comment: What is a "logical query tree"?

Comment: A tree data structure representing a relational algebra expression, used in query optimization.

Comment: In relational algebra, a join is a composition of a cartesian product and a selection, so the answer to "when to use cartesian product" is probably "always". If you need help applying this to your concrete problem (or to check if it applies to your problem), you would need to elaborate on your concrete problem.